# How to create Event & handler correctly

Tags: event-handling

I have property:

```
private bool isAuthenticated;
```

And I need to intercept when this property is changed to execute some code.

I create event:

```
public event EventHandler Authenticated;
```

and handler:

```
   public void OnAuthenticated(EventArgs e)
    {
        EventHandler handler = Authenticated;
        if (handler!= null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
```

But I have no idea how I can fix my task with it.

Sorry for my bad english...

Comment: do you have any idea where in code this property is changing?

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you rather make use of a [property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/65zdfbdt.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1), and do what ever checks you wish, or raise the event if you have to, in the setter?

Have a look at [How to: Implement Property Change Notification](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743695.aspx)